# Webkit for a contact form doesn't work on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, contact-form

Here is my HTML/CSS for a simple email contact form. It works perfectly on Mozilla but doesn't work on Chrome. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my webkit.

Here is HTML:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" class="text-center">
        <ul class="form-style" style="list-style-type: none;">
            <li>
                <label>Имя:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" size="30" maxlength="40"></li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <li>
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="40"></li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <li>
                <label>Заявка:</label>
                <textarea name="message" class="field-long textarea-field"></textarea></li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить"></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.form-style {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 400px;
padding: 20px 12px 10px 20px;
border: 1px solid green;
}
.form-style li {
padding: 0;
display: block;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.form-style-1 label {
margin: 0 0 3px 0;
padding: 0px;
display: block;
}
.form-style input[type=text],
textarea {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
padding: 7px;
margin: 0px;
outline: none;
}
.form-style .field-textarea {
height: 100px;
}
.form-style .field-long {
width: 100%;
}
.form-style input[type=submit],
.form-style input[type=button] {
background: #69B47C;
padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
border: none;
color: #fff;
}
.form-style input[type=submit]:hover,
.form-style input[type=button]:hover {
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
background: #36603E;
}
```

I tryed to apply block attribute to CSS properties but it didn't work out. As you can see, I also put my webkit before other attributes but nothing changed.

[Mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyi7t.png)

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC40J.png)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Also you have some transitions but nothing to change.

Comment: The whole style for the form. It is pure HTML on Chrome. On Mozilla there are borders, colours and the rest. I also deleted transitions because I forgot to delete it in the last edit.

Comment: Does it work when you add an unprefixed `transition: all …`? Chrome doesn't use `-webkit` prefixes for about 5 years now IIRC. // Edit: ah, i see you removed transitions altogether… So what exactly is wrong with the form rendering in Chrome?

Comment: @helb no, it doesn't work. I just tried it. Ah, sorry. I added transitions again anf then add transition: all... And it is still dead.

Comment: @helb please see my edit in the post. I included images.

Comment: I don't see any new edits :( However, as @ZeWebDev wrote in the first comment, you need to change the property to see a transition. Eg. `button { color: #f00; width: 100px; transition: all 0.33s ease; } button:hover { color: #00f; width: 120px; }` will animate color and width change.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean the form is showing all the css https://i.imgur.com/c5nISCq.png. Are you using a terribly outdated version of Chrome?

Comment: Okay. I will try it. Thank you! :)

Comment: @ZeWebDev How strange! :( I will check it.

Comment: @Olga: Here's a codepen with your code if you want to play with it. Looks pretty much the same in Chrome 63 and Firefox 56. I've added transition to the submit button. https://codepen.io/helb/pen/YraOaO

Comment: @Olga I have no problem with the style in Chrome too. What version are you using?

Comment: @sjahan I am using the latest version, just checked.

Comment: @helb I open my page with Chrome and it works BUT when I upload my file  to the server and open a website in Chrome, all the same. The style is not applyed to my contact form. However, the rest of the page is okay. Then I open the website in Mozilla and the style is applyed to everything, including the contact form. 

I'm going crazy! :D

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of stylesheet cached in Chrome? Try refreshing the page with `Shift + F5` to reload cached files.

Comment: @helb I just figured out. I cleaned my cache and it works now. So stupid! I am sorry and thank you for your help!